# Highish power/frequency sine wave generator

Tags: waveform, ultrasound

Below I'm showing an excitation signal for an ultrasonic system I'm curious about. It is driving ~ a 10 ohm load (outputting 5 watts). Does anyone have an idea what circuit would generate a waveform like this? It is unusual to me that it is a pretty pure sine wave on the down swing and back to near the crossover, but then looks like it is modulated with a 10 times higher frequency signal on the rest of the waveform.

[image: Waveform (and my finger)]

Edit: This is an ultrasonic misting/dispersal system. Your points are well taken in the comments. What does the typical driving circuit in ultrasonics look like? Some type of DDS with high gain bandwidth COTS amplifier? Or transformer for gain and LC filter? Or something else I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Can't snoop inside the source? Waveform looks vaguely class E, if that gives you any ideas what to maybe search for.

Comment: Can you run it without the piezo load?

Comment: @TimWilliams Probably could and might, was just consulting the hive mind first as I don't have a lot of experience with ultrasonics specifically.

Comment: @Bryan it's too smart and won't try without the load

Comment: What kind of ultrasonic system? A micropositioner by any chance?

Comment: It is quite doubtful that this waveform was actually intended to be as distorted as it is. Most likely, a waveform closer to a pure sinewave was desired but limitations of the amplifier and the complex impedance of the transducer resulted in the pictured signal. Note that ultrasonic transducers are generally driven at their resonant frequency and thus will filter out a lot of the distortion products of the driving signal.

Comment: Those "spurii" could be due to the way you're probing. Or your 'scope probe could be enhancing/modifying squiggles that are really there. Those spikes may be a consequence of a switch-type driver (hence @TimWilliams suggestion of Class-E). Many real-world L's & C's used in a driver circuit have additional (undesired) reactive properties.